# Job has many Applicants.. However, I can not get Job parameters to come over to the Applicant Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, form-for

User can view jobs and then fill out application. I.E. job has many applications. When creating new application, the appropriate job attributes are not coming over to the form.

I do have the relationship set up correctly. I am not correctly passing the parameters. When I create a new application, it does find the job_id. However, when on the application form, I would like more of the job attributes to show up, such as job.title. I think it is an issue with my controller.

applications_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_application, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /applications
  # GET /applications.json
  def index
    @applications = Application.all
  end

  # GET /applications/1
  # GET /applications/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /applications/new
  def new
    @application = Application.new
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  end

  # GET /applications/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /applications
  # POST /applications.json
  def create
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @application = Application.new(application_params)
    @application.job = @job
    name = @job.title

    respond_to do |format|
      if @application.save
        format.html { redirect_to @application, notice: 'Application was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @application }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /applications/1
  # PATCH/PUT /applications/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @application.update(application_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @application, notice: 'Application was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @application }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /applications/1
  # DELETE /applications/1.json
  def destroy
    @application.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to applications_url, notice: 'Application was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_application
      @application = Application.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def application_params
      params[:application]
    end

     def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :status)
    end
end
```

This is the table I have in jobs/index.html.erb  --> It has the link that launches new application... Am I supposed to be passing in local variables here?

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3"> Current Job Openings</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= job.title %></td>
          <td><%= job.description  %></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="newave-button medium grey move pull-right" style="color: white"><%= link_to 'Online Application', new_job_application_path(job) %></button></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This actually launches applications/new.html.erb which simply contains a partial to render a new form:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

And finally, here is my applications/_form.html.erb that is being rendered. I would like to relate the job specific info at the top of the page..

```
<%= link_to 'Back', jobs_path, class: "newave-button medium grey move" %>

<%= form_for [@job, @application] do |f| %>
  <% if @application.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h3><%= pluralize(@application.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this application from being saved:</h3>

      <ul>
      <% @application.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="container small-width" id="application-form">

    <h2>Personal Information</h2>
  <%= params %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :full_name, "Name" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :full_name%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit Form", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In regards to displaying `Job` fields, you've got access to the `@job` instance variable which you set up in the `new` action. You can access any `Job` information you like through that variable. However, you keep using the word *relate* but that is making the question very confusing. By *relate*, do you mean *display*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. For clarity: I am just trying to get the job.title to appear on the form. That way when the application is created, it is associated with a specific job.

Comment: Ok. Are you uncertain how associations works? You're mentioning job title, however this is an attribute of the `Job` model, and has nothing to do directly with the application itself. However, the association between `Application` and `Job` is made through a column on the `Application` table; specifically (unless you deliberately changed the name), it should be called `job_id`. If you examine the `action` URL of the rendered form, it already contains the `job_id`, which is available to rails when you submit the form. Is that the issue?

Comment: I am familiar, just new... It does show the job_id... All I want is for it to show the job title as well..... Why is the only accessible parameter job_id?  These are the job attributes: just need job.title as well..`[#<Job id: 1, title: "Test", description: "This is a test description", status: "open", created_at: "2014-12-01 04:54:22", updated_at: "2014-12-01 04:54:22">]`

Comment: So when I include <%= params %> on the form view.. to see the params this is what I see `{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"applications", "job_id"=>"1"}` Essentially.. how do I add job.title?

Comment: Admittedly I may still not quite understand what you have in mind, so let me know if I'm off. If I understand correctly, you want to add the job title in to the parameter map when creating an `Application` object so that the `Application` has the job title in it as well? If so, that goes back to what I was saying before, that the job title is irrelevant to the `Application` class. When you create the `Application`, it will be associated with the job, which has the title. Later on, you can simply do `@application.job.title` in order to see the title for that application.

Comment: You've got the right idea `create` action, basically. The only issue I see is your `application_params` method will filter out all the other parameters; you'll want to finish writing the permitted parameters before proceeding.

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct!! So how do I map the params in order to be able to do @application.job.title?

Comment: You should be getting the `job_id` when you submit the form, non? I think you indicated you are, and its accessible via `params[:job_id]`.  Or do you mean how do you finish the `application_params` method? If the latter, probably something like this: `params.require(:application).permit(:job_id, :full_name, [other attributes as needed])`

Comment: Yes I do get the job_id when I submit the form... And applications_controller.rb, I have it posted above. I believe I do have the appropriate method?

Comment: No no, that's the **job_params** method, not the **application_params** method. The `job_params` method shouldn't even be there, since this is the `ApplicationsController`; you can get rid of it, its not doing anything.

Comment: params.require(:application).permit(:job_id, #{:title OR :job_title}) <---- Which is correct?

Comment: Oh dear...neither. :p Just get it out of your mind the need to have the job title in the parameters for the application. You've got the job id, and you're associating the job with the application when it is created. That's all you need to do.

Comment: haha ok. So I now have this on my applications controller:  
`def application_params
      params[:application].permit(:job_id)
    end`
And I should be able to use <%= @application.job.title  %> on the application form view. I am still getting an error... What did I miss?

Comment: You'll probably want to add your `:full_name` field in there too which I see is in your form, but otherwise, yes that appears to be correct.  Think of it this way; the only parameters that are necessary in the form (and consequently, in the `params`), are the ones that are directly relevant for the `Application` object. Job id **is** relevant because you need that to know which `Job` object you're associating, but job title **is not**, because you can get it through the associated job.

Comment: So the form is actually like 30+ fields long.. I just cut them out for the purposes of this demonstration... That does make sense now... But when I try and call @application.job.title the error I receive is undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass... The trace of the inclusion is app/views/applications/new.html.erb   .... Do I need to add something too new.html.erb? I have it posted above,, it is just a render 'form' link

Comment: Oh ok, that goes back to my first comment. You've got the `@job` variable already setup in the `new` action, so if you just want to **display** the title on the page, you can just do `@job.title`.

Comment: Okkk... So that does work now... Thanks for taking the time to explain the process more thoroughly to me. It was very helpful.. And much appreciated! (we have only been using comments, if you post to an answer I will accept it)

Comment: No problem. I'm going to post a form answer below in a minute so we can clean this up and close this off, if you wouldn't mind upvoting / clicking the accept button (green checkmark) when it comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, you're attempting to add the job title in to the `Application` form / parameter map when creating an Application object so that the Application has the job title in it as well.

Based on our discussion and your description, the `job_title` field is an attribute of the  Job model, and has nothing to do directly with the application itself. The association between Application and Job is made through a column on the Application table called (unless you deliberately changed the name) `job_id`. If you examine the action URL of the rendered form, it already contains the job_id, which is available to rails when you submit the form in the parameter map. As you're already doing in the `create` action in the controller, you can access it via `params[:job_id]`. Basically, you've got the right idea `create` action.

Think of it this way; the only parameters that are necessary in the `Application` form (and consequently, in the params), are the ones that are directly relevant for the Application object. Job id **is** relevant because you need that to know which Job object you're associating, but job title **is not**, because you can get it through the associated job.

Regarding your question on how to access the job title in the `new` form for display purposes, as mentioned, you've already set up a `@job` variable in the controller. You can simply access the job title like so: `@job.title`. The reason why `@application.job.title` didn't work is because we haven't associated it yet. Remember that the `new` and `create` actions are completely separate, and its in the `create` action where you'll be making that association.